# Why does C compare 3 as equal to 3.0?

Tags: c, types, comparison, implicit-conversion

The problem is I can't understand how computer understood that 3 and 3.0 are the same in the very first place.

I think INT would get implicitly converted to FLOAT?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int a=3;
    float b=3.0;
    if(a==b)
        printf("s");
    else
        printf("w");
    return 0;
}
```

I'm expecting the output of the code to be w, but the actual output is s.
why? and please explain to me the perspective of the computer.

Comment: You should definitely read [that article](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/c-in-a/0596006977/ch04.html).

Comment: ... and also [that article](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion).

Comment: In what mental model would they not be equal?

Comment: Unlike some other values, floating point `3.0` can be *exactly* represented by `float` and `double` (the code uses both). So the comparison holds true, no matter which type is converted to the other.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's your reasoning for not expecting them to be equal?

Comment: In a strongly typed language, it would be illegal to compare them at all without an explicit type coercion. In a more weakly typed language, the integer would be up-converted and compare equal to within the limits of the float type. I know of no language in which the comparison would be allowed and always false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case of numbers, anyway, the equality operator `==` does not mean "Are these two things identical in every way?"  What it means is, "Do these two things have the same value?"

The integer `3` and the floating-point number `3.0` clearly have the same value, so `if(3 == 3.0)` is true.

Similarly, on an ASCII machine, the value of the `'A'` character is 65, so  `if('A' == 65)` is true, even though the letter A and the number 65 might look like very different things at first.

Answer (score 2):

In this expression

```
a==b
```

there is used the usual arithmetic conversions to determine the common type of the operands. As a result the integer object `a` is converted to the floating type `float`.

From the C Standard (6.5.9 Equality operators)

> 4 If both of the operands have arithmetic type, the usual arithmetic
>   conversions are performed...

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that `int` gets implicitly converted to `float` in this case. Generally, when a relational or binary operation is made in C which require common types, then the operands undergo implicit conversion according to a set of rules, see details [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion).

From the perspective of the computer (or rather the implementors of `C`) this is about keeping things simple. Consider the equality operator `==`. This needs to be defined for each possible combination of types of left and right hand operands. If we (for example) have 10 different data types, the `==` operator must be implemented in 10*10=100 variants to support all combinations. Converting data types so the operands always have the same type reduces the variants of the `==` operator to 10.

One remark to your example: testing for equality with `float` or `double` types is normally avoided because the computer does not have infinite precision and rounding can cause floating point numbers which are expected to be equal to be slightly different.